# Passing data from components in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

My objective is when the user clicks a message displayed on /messages, it redirects them to /message with the messages displayed information. Please direct me in the right direction if I'm doing something wrong.

**This is my error:**

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'messages' since it isn't a known property of 'message'. ("ge-header">{{user.name}}</h2>
  <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <message [ERROR ->][messages]="message"></message>
    Inbox: <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;">
   "): MessagesComponent@3:13
'message' is not a known element:
1. If 'message' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'message' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("class="page-header">{{user.name}}</h2>
  <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;">
    [ERROR ->]<message [messages]="message"></message>
    Inbox: <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: no"): MessagesComponent@3:4 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

**Messages Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages',
  templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css']
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  messages: Object;
  username: String;
  user: Object;
  messageID: String;
  public UserList: Object;
  public RecpList: Object;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
      this.username = profile.user.username;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });

    this.authService.getMessages(this.username).subscribe(list => {
        this.UserList = list.UserList;
        this.RecpList = list.RecpList;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  onMessageClick(messageID){
    this.authService.getMessage(this.user, messageID).subscribe(list => {
      console.log(list);
      this.router.navigate(['/message', ]);
    });

  }
}
```

**Messages html:**

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <h2 class="page-header">{{user.name}}</h2>
  <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <message [messages]="message"></message>
    Inbox: <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;">
      <li *ngFor="let message of RecpList" (click)="onMessageClick(message.messageID)" class="list-group" style="text-align: center;"><strong>{{message.createdBy}}</strong> {{message.subject}} <strong>{{message.dateCreated}}</strong></li>
    </ul>
    Sent: <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;">
      <li *ngFor="let message of UserList" (click)="onMessageClick(message.messageID)" class="list-group" style="text-align: center;"><strong>{{message.recipients}}</strong> {{message.subject}} <strong>{{message.dateCreated}}</strong></li>
    </ul>
  <li class="list-group"><a [routerLink] = "['/newmessage']">New Message</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Message Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.css'],
  inputs: ['messages']
})
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
messages: Object;
user: Object;
createdBy: String;
recipients: String;
subject: String;
message: String;
previousMessage: String;
nextMessage: String;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }



}
```

**Message html:**

```
<p>{{messages.subject}}</p>
```

This is my component structure
[image: File structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like a couple of things:

1. You need to include the id or message in here `this.router.navigate(['/message', ]);` which is looks like you may have missed adding it in there
2. You need to specify the path in your router like this `{ path: 'message/:id', component: MessageComponent }`
3. You can retrieve what is passed in by getting it from the params using something like this:

   this.message = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
   });

Comment: Is that specified router path in the messages component or in my main app component where I specify all the paths?

Comment: correct, yeah that would be where you specify all the other paths

Comment: Also this is a good explanation: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

Comment: I passed the object like this this.router.navigate(['/message'], messages);
Is that correct?

Comment: Are you trying to pass multiple messages? Cause then you would want to pass it in like this queryParams = {ids: [messageId,messagedId2]}. And then the router would be: this.router.navigate(['/message',queryParams ]

Comment: And then in the router path change `:id` to `:ids` and same when trying to receive the ids

Comment: You're amazing! :) Thanks so much! The link was extremely descriptive